# Getting invalid ID and Name in mvc razor when model has navigation property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is my razor code in the View.

```
int pmtcount = 0;
if (item.ProjectMaterialTypes != null)
{                                       
@foreach (var x in item.ProjectMaterialTypes)
{
pmtcount = pmtcount + 1;                            
@Html.HiddenFor(model =>model.ProjectTypes[ptcount - 1].ProjectMaterialTypes.ToList()[pmtcount - 1].ProjectMaterialTypeID, new { Value = x.ProjectMaterialTypeID})
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectTypes[ptcount - 1].ProjectMaterialTypes.ToList()[pmtcount - 1].MaterialTypes.Name, new { Value = x.MaterialTypes.Name })
<label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ProjectTypes[ptcount - 1].ProjectMaterialTypes.ToList()[pmtcount - 1].Status, new { @onclick = "togglesingle('smt-" + x.MaterialTypeID + "')" }) @x.MaterialTypes.Name</label>
}
}
```

Populating Id and name like this on the browser.
[image]

But getting null object in the controller by submitting the form, Please let me know is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Your image text is not readable.

Comment: @Kaf, I updated my question with clear image. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Simply I changed my ICollection to List in the Model library.In this way i resolved my issue. HTML helper will generate property name when use List instead of ICollection in Entity Framework Model class.

From

```
public virtual ICollection<ProjectMaterialType> ProjectMaterialTypes { get; set; }
```

changed to

```
public virtual List<ProjectMaterialType> ProjectMaterialTypes { get; set; }
```